# Prestashop: Class 'ObjectModel' not found

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to tap into Prestashop in order to bulk import a lot of product images from a web service.

I want to use `adminProducts->addProductImage($object)` but I have struggled for hours trying to instantiate that class (or any other class for the matter).

No matter what I do I always get a `class 'ObjectModel' not found in xxx.php on line nnn`.

I have tried including `ObjectModel.php` but apparently the base class ObjectModel is not declared in that file. The big problem is that it doesn't seem to be declared *anywhere*!

**So my question is: How do I load ObjectModel in order to satisfy all the other classes it extends?**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer for your question but it should solve your problem. 
My advice is create with a script a csv file with the id, name and coma separated links to files like this

102;"iPad";"http://link.to/img/1.jpg","http://link.to/img/2.jpg"

and use import feature in the backoffice.

It's easier and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an option. The context is data from a SOAP web service that needs to go into the database using a cronjob.